# change the value of parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help to change the value "allNews" after clicking the button .all_news

http://plnkr.co/edit/xKVpczgVa9wKtIpS95ng?p=preview

as a result of the class .allNews should be added to the block .slide_panel_inner and block height increase to 600px

Comment: the link is broken, I advise pasting code snippets directly here or in a more permanent place with the relevant code pasted here.

Comment: @omouse yes, he should have included code, but the link isn't broken. plnkr is just weird like that some times.

Answer (score 1):

As you can easily see in the console log (f12), you are getting an error because of your mis-use of ng-class. All you need to do is something like this:

```
<button ng-click="toggleClass()">Toggle Class</button>
<div ng-class="myDivClass"></div>
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.myDivClass= ''; //no class applied
$scope.toggleClass = function() {
  $scope.myDivClass = ($scope.myDivClass) ? '' : 'my-class-name-here'; //turn class on or off
};
```

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/OBanuVa/1/edit)